# C++ System function "not reconized as internal or external command"

Tags: c++, system

So here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "type dir" << endl;
    string command;
    cin >> command;  //typed C:\Java
    const char* cml = ("cd C:" + command).c_str();
    system(cml);
    cout << "[System]: Set!";
}
```

and here is the result:

```
'exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I just type system("cd C:\Java");, then it works. but if I pass in the const char into the system function like above, I get an error that exe is not reconized.

Comment: The only difference I can see from your post is the back slash?

Comment: I assume this is windows.   Does it give a similar error if you call `system("echo hello")`.   `echo` is built into the default command interpreter (`CMD`) - actioned by the command interpret itself, rather than a separate executable.   If that system call doesn't work, either your system is misconfigured, or has been configured to use a different command line processor that doesn't behave as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior:

```
const char* cml = ("cd C:" + command).c_str();
```

The `cml` variable is being initialized with the C-string pointer from the `std::string` returned as result of the concatenation. However, this result is a temporary variable that is discarded just after this statement ends. So, the character array pointer to by `cml` is already freed after this line.

The following does keep the concatenation result alive for usage in the next statements:

```
string cml = "cd C:" + command
system(cml.c_str())
```

Comment: Technically the undefined behaviour does not come until the dangling pointer is used on the next line